# App exiting after GPS enable in android

Tags: android, gps

With in app checking GPS is enabled or not once GPS is not enabled showing this alertbox

```
    private void showGpsAlert() throws Exception {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashActivity.this);

    alertDialogBuilder
    .setTitle("предупреждение")
    .setMessage("Включите службы определения местоположения , чтобы позволить\"Kupon\" Для определения своего местоположения")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setNegativeButton("не позволяют",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            SplashActivity.this.finish();
        }
    })
    .setPositiveButton("позволять", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            //dialog.dismiss();
            final Intent intent = new Intent(
                    Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.show();
    TextView messageText = (TextView) alertDialog
            .findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

But after enabling GPS in settings if user click on back button app is exiting without entering in to app,What is problem in my code i didn't get.Help pls

Comment: `startActivityForResult(intent, 1);`? just start activity, dont wait for intent result

Comment: Yes i tried StartActivity() then also same problem

Answer (score 0):

override one more method of activity class -

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

it will open your activity.

Comment: I am calling this alert box from onActivityResult please look in to my class http://pastebin.com/x0LGqLph

Comment: replace line number 119 of your activity code from  startActivity(intent); to startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

Comment: ihave used startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE); but if you see above answer as per answer  i have changed to startActivity().I am using this alert on splash screen ,is it creating problem ?please check once

Comment: use gps alert  on login screen, and you can also check your logic of user login status on login screen and open activity accordingly.